# Overload resolution based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm unsure if what I want to do is possible in C++, so asking here.

I have a templated class `MyClass` that has an optional template argument `idx`. I have another non-templated class `OtherClass`. What I want to do is to do some sort of overload resolution based on `idx`:

- If `idx` is provided (has a value other than -1), I want to call the templated version of `OtherClass::otherMethod`.
- Otherwise, I want to call the non-templated version of `OtherClass::otherMethod`.

Note that if `T==SomeType` the user of `MyClass` would provide `idx`. In other cases, no `idx` is needed. Also, the two different versions of `OtherClass::otherMethod` are guaranteed to take different input types. Seems to me that I somehow need to disable overload resolution for `OtherClass::otherMethod<>`  when `idx == -1` and enable it only if `idx!= -1`.

The code below outlines what I have:

```cpp
template <typename T, int32_t idx=-1>
class MyClass
{
    OtherClass m_other;

    void myMethod(T arg)
    {
        // If idx == -1
        // m_other.otherMethod<idx>(arg);

        // else
        // m_other.otherMethod(arg);
    }
}

class OtherClass
{

    template<int32_t idx>
    void otherMethod(SomeType arg)
    {
        // Some operation that depends on idx
    }

    void otherMethod(YetAnotherType arg)
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
One obvious solution is to template `void otherMethod(YetAnotherType arg)` with some default (and unused) argument. I'm looking for solutions other than that.

**EDIT2:**  (in response to comments)
I'm using C++11. A simple `if` doesn't always work, [as demonstrated here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJzlki92U). Thus, I need to know whether what I need to do is possible with compile-time constructs.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what would be the problem with the direct approach: `if (idx == -1) { ... } else { ... }`, why that doesn't work for you. You also need to clarify which C++ version you are using, because there are several possible solutions that depend on the C++ version you are using: C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20?

Comment: Updated the question. I'm purely interested in knowing whether this is possible with template magic and compile-time constructs

Comment: Also, please feel free to post non-C++11 solutions too. I'm purely interested in learning here

Comment: **Why** aren't you using a simple `if`?  There is zero runtime cost from it.  "I don't want to use it" isn't an explanation.

Comment: Actually I just realized with an 'if' you could run into compilation errors if you have two different T types. Plus, educational question, remember?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont @SamVarshavchik Updated the question yet again, providing a counter-example with **compilation error** with `if` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T, int32_t idx=-1>
class MyClass {
  OtherClass m_other;

  void myMethodHelper(T arg, std::true_type) {
       m_other.otherMethod<idx>(arg);
  }
  void myMethodHelper(T arg, std::false_type) {
       m_other.otherMethod(arg);
  }

public:
  void myMethod(T arg) {
    myMethodHelper(arg, std::integral_constant<bool, (idx >= 0)>{});
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z8mNzd)

Comment: Very cool! Basically, we're doing the overload resolution ourselves based on `idx` at compile time. Would you mind updating the code snippet to match the demo you provided?

Comment: This technique is known as "tag dispatch". You can find more discussion if you search for this phrase.